# Mock para método chamado por outros métodos usando jest ou vitest

Tags: javascript, typescript, testes, jest

Supondo dois métodos.

```
export function dummyMethod() {
  return 'dummy';
}

export function main() {
  dummyMethod();
  return 'spied execution complete';
}
```

Como eu posso verificar se realmente `dummyMethod` foi chamado dentro de `main` usando mocks no jest? Escrevi os testes abaixo mas particularmente o mock sempre retorna 0. Testando manualmente sei que o método é chamado.

```
import { it, expect, describe, vi } from 'vitest';
import { dummyMethod, main } from '../data';

vi.mock(dummyMethod);

describe("main", () => {

  it("should return a string", () => {
    const result = main();
    const dummyMethodMocked = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'dummy'); 
    expect(result).toBe('spied execution complete');
    expect(dummyMethodMocked).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O método [`mock`](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/bypassing-module-mocks) espera um **objeto para ser mockado**, mas você está passando uma **função**. Em vez de chamar `vi.mock(dummyMethod)`, você deve criar uma implementação falsa (`mock`) de `dummyMethod` com `jest.fn`.

```
import { it, expect, describe } from 'vitest';
import { dummyMethod, main } from '../data';

jest.mock('../data', () => {
  return {
    dummyMethod: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'dummy'), // fazemos o mock aqui
    main: jest.requireActual('../data').main                  // matém o comportamento original de `main`
  };
});

describe("main", () => {
  it("should return a string", () => {
    const result = main();
    expect(result).toBe('spied execution complete');
    expect(dummyMethod).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  });
});
```

Use o `jest.mock` para substituir o módulo `../data` com uma versão que usa uma implementação **falsa** de `dummyMethod`. Isso permite que você verifique se `dummyMethod` foi chamado ao executar `main`.

A chamada [`jest.requireActual`](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) permite que voce mantenha a implementação original de `main`.

---

Lembrando que [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) é baseado em [Jest](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/), então muito do que você pode fazer com Jest, você faz usando Vitest.

Comment: Deu certo, após eu mover `dummy` para outro arquivo e isolá-lo da função testada. Aparentemente não podemos criar mocks com funções que estejam no mesmo arquivo que a função que principal para ser testada. Mocks só podem ser:

**modulos que importamos dentro do arquivo**
ou **callbacks que passamos dentro de uma função**

Por isso separar a função em outro arquivo e usar o código que você escreveu, fez os testes passarem. Muito obrigado